# return a list inside a list including the longest word from a list of tuples

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples:

```py
[('One', 3), ('two', 3), ('three', 5)]
[('Those', 5), ('whom', 4), ('the', 3), ('gods', 4), ('love', 4), ('grow', 4), ('young', 5)]
```

I would like to return the longest word from each list if they are equivalent both should be returned like so:

```
[["three", 5]]
[["Those", 5],["young", 5]]
```

how could this be implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the length of each word is part of the tuple pair, you can use a conditional list comprehension checking each word against the max word length:

```
max_word_length = max(tup[1] for tup in my_list)
[pair for pair in my_list 
 if pair[1] == max_word_length]
```

You could also use `filter`:

```
list(filter(lambda x: x[1] == max_word_length, my_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using list comprehensions:

```
>>> l1 = [('One', 3), ('two', 3), ('three', 5)]
>>> l2 = [('Those', 5), ('whom', 4), ('the', 3), ('gods', 4), ('love', 4), ('grow', 4), ('young', 5)]
>>> max_l1_len = max(y for _, y in l1)
>>> max_l2_len = max(y for _, y in l2)
>>> [(x, y) for x, y in l1 if y == max_l1_len]
[('three', 5)]
>>> [(x, y) for x, y in l2 if y == max_l2_len]
[('Those', 5), ('young', 5)]
```

Or if you want list of lists instead of list of tuples:

```
>>> [[x, y] for x, y in l1 if y == max_l1_len]
[['three', 5]]
>>> [[x, y] for x, y in l2 if y == max_l2_len]
[['Those', 5], ['young', 5]]
```